# How to implement TDD and Integration Testing, without Repository model, on ASP.Net MVC

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, integration

Our group is just starting out on TDD and Unit Testing. We've started down the path of the Repository Model, and are dubious. It seems to only test small sections of code while requiring a great amount of coding time. We also find that the greatly increased complexity is harder to support. When coupled with the fact that so much business logic, that in SQL, or in the UI layer, is left without coverage and requires even more complexity to cover that code, ....it seems like such a waste of time.

Don't get me wrong, I want to implement TDD, but I want a complete solution that tests from UI to DB. Yes I know that this is called Integration Testing, and I really don't understand why some are so eager to point out that IT is greatly different from UT, that's obvious. But why would you choose UT, bring so much complexity, and getting so little coverage in return for your effort.

What ways have you implemented TDD, using integration testing?

Comment: User Blue Clouds has a post elsewhere that indicates he has had success with this, I would love for him to contribute to the thread.

Comment: You may take a look on MVC (MVP) architecture, which makes biz logic code very rare (and trivial only) in UI layers. The pure "model" layers tend to be lot more easy to test with UT (although procedures stored in DB and closely coupled code with DB may be more tricky, in one of my projects I had such part of functionality in DB, that I rather run UT over temporary memory database, sacrificing some UT speed (from ~1s to ~10s), to not mock too much in the tests). In that particular project I even didn't use UI layers tests at all, as the UI was trivial thin layer over the model, but YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

TDD can often get blamed for increased complexity and being hard to maintain but in my experience this isn't the result of TDD alone. TDD promotes loose coupling which generally leads to more classes but more succinct classes, if you come from a coding style where you tend to have bigger classes with hidden dependencies then at first glance TDD does look like it increases complexity. But in actuality its revealing all the dependencies that were there but more than likely hidden.

With TDD you should be writing less code as you only write enough code to make your unit test pass, but your code tends to be split into smaller chunks. On my current project we practice TDD and have a large number of unit tests obviously these are written first, we also have integration tests to make sure the layers play nicely together but an integration test is simply testing the sum of the parts which we already know (for the most part) are working. We also have a UI test suite built with selenium.

One final note is when doing TDD you can go too far in abstracting things, I always look to the rule of 3 to keep me inline https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

> But why would you choose UT, bring so much complexity, and getting so
>   little coverage in return for your effort?

Once you get your dependencies injected, UT shouldn't really cost too much to implement. I'd go for UT when targeting a certain class that has a considerable amount of logic inside (switches, lots of ifs etc).

You'll want to use IT to assert that a scenario from a certain family is working end2end (click on a register button, create a user, assert against the DB for example). You're not going to use IT to cover all the scenarios and ifs in the code because it's a lot more expensive (that also means slow) than UT.

That being said, you might want to move logic from the UI/DB more into the backend (although there certainly are tools for isolating & testing the UI) - your solution might be more easy to manage this way, and thus easier to scale (if that's a possibility).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!